# How do hooks replace components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[*Hooks*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), as I understand them, are just a way to add state (and lifecycle methods) to `function` components.

This FAQ answer:

> *In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.*
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

and this documentation snippet:

> *Hooks let you split one component into smaller functions based on what pieces are related*
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

confuse me slightly as a React beginner.

It is as if I have to think about my app in terms of *hooks* rather than in terms of *elements* and *components*.

React didn't remove components, but the quote hints that hooks will replace
components as the primary source of *code reuse*.

Can one still talk about elements and components as primary abstractions in React?

Comment: Hooks themselves will not replace components, they are not comparable things. The React folks see function components *using hooks* replacing class components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of components is not going away, it's just how they are written that is changing.

The second line you quoted

> Hooks let you split one component into smaller functions based on what pieces are related

Is poorly worded in my opinion, and should rather say "Hooks let you split one class component into **smaller functional components**..."

So instead of having one monolithic class that handles all state and lifecycle logic in methods like componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, you can split areas of concern and have smaller functional components that only care about things directly related to themselves.

---

*Edit*: This snippet from the hooks-intro doc might be helpful:

> Hooks don’t replace your knowledge of React concepts. Instead, Hooks provide a more direct API to the React concepts you already know: props, state, context, refs, and lifecycle. As we will show later, Hooks also offer a new powerful way to combine them.

Comment: A functional component is still just a function that returns JSX, per this documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html. Ruffengs comment to his answer sums it up well. Hooks are just a function, they do not replace components. It's the functional components using hooks that can replace other components.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are 2 ways of building components in React:

1. Class Component
2. Functional Component

[You can check them here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). The way you build it it's different. In case you approach the class component, that means that you need to work with the [prototype of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

On the other side, if you choose to go as a functional component, that means that everything you request from React, is invoking a function, and not using the prototype at all. All this chaining from JS can slow down the performance, and that's why the React core team decided to go into pure functional direction: It can perform better, and it makes it even simpler to read it (once you get used to it).

Regarding the second quotation. It is a way to show more benefits of functional programming over classes. They are more flexible and can have a better composition for it.

One last addition: Approaching functional components doesn't mean you can ignore to learn class components. There's still a lot of apps with some legacy code. I would recommend learning both, and whenever you need to create new components, approach the functional component paradigm.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough post! Unfortunately, though, this is more of a comment than an answer to my question.

Comment: Hook is just a function. Component is a composition of JSX with React. That's why hooks will never replace components, nor elements.